# Error when calling x11() from any R instance (RStudio, Terminal, Visual Studio Code)

Tags: r, macos, x11

I have some issues with plotting with R on Mac

[image]

when I try to plot something. Just a simple call of `x11()` results in an error. Calling it from a terminal I got:

```
 R 

 R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05) -- "Action of the Toes"
 Copyright (C) 2019 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
 Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
 > x11()
   Fehler in .External2(C_X11, d$display, d$width, d$height, d$pointsize,  : 
   kann Device X11 nicht starten
   Zusätzlich: Warnmeldung:
   In x11() : konnte Verbindung zu X11 display '' nicht öffnen
```

Calling x11() from RStudio the whole application is freezing. My target is to use Visual Studio Code for working with R. Therefore a bug fix for RStudio will unfortunately not help.

Thanks for your support!

Comment: what's the output of `capabilities('X11)`? are you using a local or remote installation of R?

Comment: a workaround might be to use cairo instead of X11 with `options(bitmapType = 'cairo')`

Comment: Unfortunately setting option does not help

Answer (score 0):

From the [R for Mac OS X FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/RMacOSX-FAQ.html) you can see that you need to install XQuartz, because X11 is no longer included in the newer versions of the OS (since Mac OS X 10.9)

You can download it from the XQuartz homepage: https://www.xquartz.org/

After the installation, `capabilities('X11')` should return `TRUE` and `X11()` should work.

Comment: Despite the installation of newest available XQuartz and reboot of the machine, `capabilities('X11')` returns `FALSE`